# Handle events through multiple layers in Kinetic.js?

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, dom-events, kineticjs

I have a circle on layer1 and then a square on layer2. The circle diameter is the square's  width, their centers are the same, and the circle is on top of the square.  How do I set things up such that if I trigger any event on layer1 the same even will be executed at the same location in layer2.  So in this case if I click on the circle, the square's click event will also be triggered.  Of course, this doesn't mean I simply want to hook up the circle's events to the square's, but rather I basically want the events to be triggered on both layers.

So for example if

```
circle.on( "click", function() {
    alert("foo");
});

square.on( "click", function() {
    alert("bar");
});
```

then clicking on the center of circle should trigger the square click event.

And NOT by

```
circle.on( "click", function() {
    alert("foo");
    square.simulate("click"); // don't want this
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about adding the circle and square to a group, and then attatch the click-event to the group instead?

Answer (score 0):

Kinetic has two things that can help you.

1. getIntersections()  -- returns all shapes under the mouse click point
2. fire() -- fires an event

The Kinetic docs mention the getIntersections() performs slowly, so they prefer getIntersection(), but I have never used either, so I can't say how much.

http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Stage.html#getIntersection

Hope this helps.